# Unable to decrypt data - openssl_private_decrypt(): key parameter is not a valid private key

Tags: php, openssl, public-key-encryption, private-key

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $config = array(
        "config" => "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\openssl.cnf",
        "private_key_bits" => 2048,
        "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    );

    // Create the private and public key
    $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);

    if ($res === false) die('Failed to generate key pair.'."\n"); 

    if (!openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey, "phrase", $config)) die('Failed to retrieve private key.'."\n"); 

    // Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey, "phrase", $config);

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Private Key = ".$privKey;
    echo "<br/>";

    // Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey
    $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    $pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Public Key = ".$pubKey;
    echo "<br/>";

    $data = 'plaintext data goes here';

    // Encrypt the data to $encrypted using the public key
    openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $pubKey);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Encrypted Data = ".$encrypted;
    echo "<br/>";

    // Decrypt the data using the private key and store the results in $decrypted
    openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $privKey);

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Decrypted Data = ".$decrypted;
    echo "<br/>";
?>
```

**LOGS**

> Private Key = -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
>   MIIFDjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIr2acPfh8YYQCAggA
>   MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAiCvohdiWAZ4QSCBMjKJUXF5ShKfW3TazpKYTxEV8JmGYLf
>   AJWXzxdi0GrDuddz4aW1FeGwvUm2t/41CTxFsWtgoQJrzCgAQETn54majdrDeF4u
>   zCmvFMKSoVP4xsZKke15e1K1LPmFNNuKKyCqMwL+tpQJ7zquvDTKHapUnNzfNXpZ
>   D2K1r2qZWeDN1d36DA9wkN5GbpZYAjuHqHUNzorhxIbHGp2WOg8YKdemoTuKIqYC
>   DUKncWtxRUOx6IIZuey+uTBzH7Bn9K9a71QTjUdeWgQZFzy9yVpetB+XrJA92IWt
>   vMeKXCXNhOgkOvkUPNXSuMOVrECNcbKDAKxmK3EQWqb+8zlYFqjmaL/sCep8ihio
>   1ZWpRaOd5HxnG5rpmz/BYzcF354mM8B4wAIk7MmFq/pHSKLjpr+2Ef1BpMmXfRpG
>   Pj1jYDClSIQF6ovKOqhevFwfYrtl2jEOISyAggm/sbD750VBkwhbVAyQcarckAiI
>   GlNcQPOC+JYZOV7o/9o+Tg24zwtAQ8y3hNvYyHjqYI5naVS9yuXEqB6zYoGivs/k
>   bIblqTFebLEFtihjsa9wpXkyNzKD2NvdSa2oNC7IkCNi8TRNjy7MLylSmCIdhWAV
>   YgL1hxShMgbnfiGjFQyYnKzZto9RqRlQBIoBOCfwP1EFnZjCJm02CCeGR+GHKXf7
>   rJ0n6lIUEvVnENirAPtOuiE2ccbzmyjWQ9f2vwBSUea5nPTMG4uTVHrQjrgNYIyU
>   +vLV6tL+MDKF4JGQGgzBUeqTMobmrOK+V20QIasYaAWHJrL8itBwZ++C8lo7kySa SImMXakI4rjgEmj+HmUJygT1EZWz5yQqOiwAYLhQZg+m6+32Pvt6mIrAXbznrdHP
>   JxHb/9HV88mQdRKPBTkSTl71Ics+3oybYPbhSQByXOdtsw6VLYNo4ikgj3tXCz01
>   DwVQqeQ5tLD4LY8/QaAHkOUq9K24yfkcN+aQh7cvR/HX53Ls6LsdUwkwSOWVj2na
>   Wl4xn+j3ZaPhpgdzcMgknU7BAI2kZP83MxyKnNcnneyX4hTaM5PRZJXKd+onvhff
>   nQ3zHDSYmRDKmTXBjCob3Vjg91LcMjg9dEH7aIFWit5dHK4ll/v1IiOFx8d4d/mV
>   Oll0c0ujJuPjtyqesM2Bz3Ah5YkIT2Z7kxvRy7rTyytQG7hLNENAki9wW79fcEo7
>   ln/OvEpjdWZngkL/UrMOX8DBrs0PLEH9jyDoCQx/LSqxMAXOwVXILfsfsUFu0M0o
>   21YbeC33jOlocJ4Q6pwfRVz8lCQOuIVs1jEpvSmvHgvmHmXUI4Y6nZD4Roi0jIjS
>   VvI73eULzc3j0jIptWxzrHWM6iHx1zRxkLMJSZOx0A27ngtSo7g6+aJnMO5FDfdR
>   90vnr+bX4ki+X/N4wVF7eppyapLe/tQ54vAxsyIBrCXPjwBMehiFjOMhzSLW7xQj
>   Qg2KcilfW6oKFzDQQ5nKPEXvQYMhQ1MeWKyNv6BMoc4EEpIGhtziUXWhgT4sN1ES
>   5sxVcGVoIe1viO/kk3Zq55hETlZbNWs3V511BcEZCiQNrntnbYv6pwKpoB21ZV2E
>   slVhYcslEGliIQKQsWSl5cfc+pqjLteiPrwk14WKJGXl9zX3YH6H7KKB/7SIRZk7 wq8=
>   -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> Public Key = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAriS8qflAjYSYhH2qgC5T
>   yf98X1qoLMXIW9mMkhV8LcApBKOfNjUMc9xjD3a8CR/LYwa4MYhevoKcVfPG8XoE
>   sDGyHh+h/vtYP0rORB1T3RULVUzDLjX558e2KqPrSN+rV+Jl1NB0SO5Of3JA+AKa
>   0Q3botcjOM3WuFa/s+RzsiCrMMhzOZSTBj+GTP/VcDipF5PM7+/Lxr+edjRXccT2
>   WQjsq0sUrtsmpzBE8Niph361RjfIisxKoksQGs7hC/Iv4yhBzZZIpRaZuvDj4ImP
>   +4sUQgbdVVCso122kg34UtY5qchuSCcJfsGbD2zMw+8ZftIsJ7dfX1FxujgggDyn 0wIDAQAB -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

```
Encrypted Data = Uš6/ùÅËæÝmL4²G¾'gr¨Ñ­Ä‰ï‚zêbÀ)[îR0s‹yÝ`t™õ°Þe­Ïd>×o¯rß9ÌÔÅAü!-†D·¨ÎVZ¼?¶éžäýöaØT~=‚Fan¢ºq{M”ƒ¹Cû5N3¹.Ð(·#*ÏRÆ¹ñß÷õƒ_ò9c-Ÿ% ×óè2ê™‚õ“ÂÐgNÈ-ˆd«…ºt§¼Ô}yŠ"7èPš(¶R¤ßJÚ_h¶ðÞK(Cj“7‘YÂ ÀŠþrôZƒ4)JU•˜„üˆ k0â§Êë^ÚºGÚªúVKø†ë8ÏLÚó  „Ÿ¦¿¤

( ! ) Warning: openssl_private_decrypt(): key parameter is not a valid private key in C:\wamp\www\android\pki_example.php on line 41
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  252696  {main}( )   ..\pki_example.php:0
2   0.2043  258032  openssl_private_decrypt ( ) ..\pki_example.php:41

Decrypted Data =
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Decrypt the data using the private key and store the results in $decrypted
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, openssl_pkey_get_private($privKey, "phrase"));

echo "<br/>";
echo "Decrypted Data = ".$decrypted;
echo "<br/>";
```

`openssl_private_decrypt` function is capable to use PEM formatted private key but your key is encrypted and this function does not have an argument for password. You have to use `openssl_pkey_get_private` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I understood that the key was encrypted that's why its not decrypting the data. right?

Comment: Yes, it was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is the reason. I think someone can edit this with exact reason.

When I use private key in one line, it gives the above error mentioned in this question.
But when I use the same private key by splitting it into several lines **(64 characters per line)** it works. In this way no need to use `openssl_pkey_get_private($privKey, "phrase")` function. Actually I had no pass phrase for my private key.

Answer (score 0):

***Please use like below code***

```
  // Create the keypair
    $privatefile = "data/privatekey.pem";
    $publicfile = "data/publickey.pem";
    $cleartextfile = "data/cleartext";
    $res = openssl_pkey_new();
    if (!$res) {
        echo "\nopenssl_pkey_new: " . openssl_error_string();
    }

    // Get private key
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $privatekey);
    if (!$privatekey) {
        echo "\nopenssl_pkey_export: " . openssl_error_string();
    }
    file_put_contents($privatefile, $privatekey);

    // Get public key
    $pkeydetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    if (!$pkeydetails) {
        echo "\nopenssl_pkey_get_details: " . openssl_error_string();
    }
    $publickey = $pkeydetails["key"];
    file_put_contents($publicfile, $publickey);
  // For getting Decrypted password
   $postedPassord= $_POST['password'];
    openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($postedPassord), 
     $decryptPassword, $privatekey);
```